# Ejercicio en Java - Multiplicaciones (No puedo sumar una variable i++)

Tags: java, while

buenas noches, he aquí que tengo un ejercicio de practica para alumnos que están aprendiendo a multiplicar.
Los alumnos tienen que responder por consola preguntas de multiplicaciones muy sencillas de 1 dígito (La cantidad de intentos debe ser igual a 10, tanto si la respuesta por consola es correcta o incorrecta).

Mi problema, es que la **variable** `intentos` (que esta iniciada a cero como atributo de la clase `Multiplicacion`, no esta aumentando de valor desde el método `verificaMultiplicar()` que a su vez llama al método en cuestion que hace la sumatoria denominado `suma()`, y no puedo entender que estoy haciendo mal, ya que se reinicia a 0, o actúa de manera antinatural. Efectivamente, hay algo que estoy haciendo mal.

Mi objetivo, es sacar un porcentaje de respuestas correctas en esos 10 intentos del alumno.
Me podrían ayudar?

Gracias

public class InstruccionAsistida {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int contador=0;

    while(contador<10) {

        Multiplicacion objeto=new Multiplicacion();

        int resultadoCorrecto=objeto.resultadoMultiplicar();

        boolean resultadoAlumno=objeto.verificaMultiplicar(resultadoCorrecto);

        while(resultadoAlumno==false) {     

            if(objeto.verificaMultiplicar(resultadoCorrecto)) {

                resultadoAlumno=true;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

}

```
class Multiplicacion{


    private boolean estado=true;

    private int intentos=0;


    public void respuestaAsertada() {

        SecureRandom aleatorioPositivo=new SecureRandom();

        int respuestaPositiva=1+aleatorioPositivo.nextInt(4);

        switch(respuestaPositiva) {

        case 1: {

            System.out.println("Muy bien!");
            break;
        }

        case 2: {

            System.out.println("Excelente!");
            break;
        }


        case 3: {

            System.out.println("Buen trabajo!");
            break;
        }

        case 4: {

            System.out.println("Sigue asi!");
            break;

        }

        }


    }

    public void respuestaDesasertada() {

        SecureRandom aleatorioNegativo=new SecureRandom();

        int respuestaNegativa=1+aleatorioNegativo.nextInt(4);

        switch(respuestaNegativa) {

        case 1: {

            System.out.println("No. Por favor intenta de nuevo");
            break;
        }

        case 2: {

            System.out.println("Incorrecto. Intenta una vez mas.");
            break;
        }


        case 3: {

            System.out.println("No te rindas!");
            break;
        }

        case 4: {

            System.out.println("No, sigue intentando!");
            break;

        }

        }


    }


    public int resultadoMultiplicar() {

        SecureRandom multiplicacionAleatoria=new SecureRandom();

        int dato1Multiplicacion=1+multiplicacionAleatoria.nextInt(9);

        int dato2Multiplicacion=1+multiplicacionAleatoria.nextInt(9);

        int resultadoFinal=dato1Multiplicacion*dato2Multiplicacion;

        System.out.println("Cuanto es " + dato1Multiplicacion + " X " + dato2Multiplicacion +"?" );

        return resultadoFinal;
    }



    public boolean verificaMultiplicar(int a) {

        estado=true;    


        Scanner entradaAlumno=new Scanner(System.in);

        int respuestaAlumno=entradaAlumno.nextInt();            

        if(respuestaAlumno==a) {

            respuestaAsertada();

            estado=true;

            suma();//ACA TENGO LA VARIABLE INTENTOS SUMANDO

        }

        else {

            respuestaDesasertada();

            estado=false;   

            suma();//ACA TENGO LA VARIABLE INTENTOS SUMANDO

        }

        return estado;
    }

    public void suma() {

        intentos++;

        System.out.println(intentos);

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que creas el objeto `Multiplicacion objeto=new Multiplicacion();` dentro del `while`. Por eso en cada iteración lo reinicia. Si quieres mantener el estado del objeto inicializalo antes del `while`

Comment: Gracias genio. Soy principiante y estas cosas me pasan..